# Comparing 2-dimensional numpy array in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, matrix

I want to comparing 2 values in a 2-dimensional numpy array. The array is as follows:

```
a = [[1, 3, 5],
     [4, 8, 1]]
```

I want to comparing `[1, 3, 5]` with `[4, 8, 1]` with a greater value into 1 group.
The result I want is like this:

```
a1 = [4, 8, 5]
a2 = [1, 3, 1]
```

How could the code be written in python?

Comment: Please be clear with your example. What you have shown is **not an array** and has *nothing to do with Numpy*, yet you have tagged the question `numpy`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.sort` on axis `0` (column-wise). Reverse the order using `[::-1]` to get them in descending order

```
>>> np.sort(a, axis = 0)[::-1]

array([[4, 8, 5],
       [1, 3, 1]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you only have 2 rows you can do this:

```
a = np.array([[1, 3, 5],
              [4, 8, 1]])

idx = np.greater(*a)

a1 = a[idx.astype(int),np.arange(3)]
a2 = a[~idx.astype(int),np.arange(3)]
```